# Rails activerecord is querying the wrong column name in HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model-view-controller, many-to-many

I have two models, lists and categories, with a many-to-many relationship, with a join table called categories_lists. When I try and get all the categories a singular list belongs to, I get the following error:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column categories_lists.category_id does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ER JOIN "categories_lists" ON "categories"."id" = "categorie...
>                                                                ^
>   HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "categories_lists.categories_id"...

View:

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <li><%= cat.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
def show
  @categories = List.find(params[:id]).categories.all
end
```

Model:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Table:

```
describe categories_lists                                                                                                                                  
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| Column        | Type   | Modifiers   |
|---------------+--------+-------------|
| categories_id | bigint |             |
| lists_id      | bigint |             |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

Its making the categories singular, instead of keeping it plural the way its defined in the model. I don't know how to correct this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for foreign keys is singular, you've got it the wrong way in your table.

You can either change it in the table to `category_id` and `list_id`, or specify the non-standard fkeys in your habtms (setting both `:foreign_key` and `:association_foreign_key` options on both sides), eg.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, association_foreign_key: :categories_id, foreign_key: :lists_id
```

### Update

From OP, the migration they used:

```rb
class ChangeColumnNamesCategoriesLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    rename_column :categories_lists, :categories_id, :category_id 
    rename_column :categories_lists, :lists_id, :list_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. The tutorial I was following used plurals for foreign keys, but of course now I can't find which tutorial I was using. I chose to rename the table columns in a migration; would it be best form to post that as a separate answer, or put the migration code in a comment here?

Comment: Up to you, the migration code itself is fairly simple.

Comment: For those following, here is the migration code to make the answer a full solution: 

```class ChangeColumnNamesCategoriesLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    rename_column :categories_lists, :categories_id, :category_id
    rename_column :categories_lists, :lists_id, :list_id
  end
end```